# Differents result equal file PHP

Tags: php

Hi I have a strange problem.

These files are equal

http://sfidasoft.com/demos/umara_new/admin/test.php

http://sfidasoft.com/matias/melipal/admin/test.php

But if you send a POST for example with "nnnnn" the results are different

www.sfidasoft.com/demos/umara_new/admin/test.php

POST "ññññ"

Result

Array ( [ss] => ññññ )

www.sfidasoft.com/matias/melipal/admin/test.php

POST "ññññ"

Result

Array ( [ss] => Ã±Ã±Ã±Ã± )

test.php

```
  <?php 
foreach($_POST as $campo =>$valor)
{
    $array[$campo] = htmlentities(addslashes(strip_tags($valor)));
}
print_r($array); 
  ?>
  <head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
  </head>
  <form action="" method="POST">
  <input type="text" name="ss">
  <input type="submit">
  </form>
```

The question is

Why is there a difference if the files are the same?

Comment: so what's the question?

Comment: If your phpinfo matches his and your server configs and version then you are more likely to be in trouble. This looks like an encoding issue. Probably one server is using UTF-8 and one is using ISO-8859-1 or something like that.

Comment: specify third argument in `htmlentities` and proper `Content-Type` header with encoding.

Answer (score 0):

it seems that a problem with character encoding

check the following:

1- u save the page with utf-8 encoding

2-check post value encoding type using  [mb_detect_encoding()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-detect-encoding.php)

Comment: ASCII for two results